# Undefined local variable or method `context' error within a Redmine hook module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine

I used a redmine view_issues_show_description_bottom hook as following:

```
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

module RedmineIssueRawFile
    class Hooks  < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
      puts "logger ............"
      #puts context[:issue]
      r = RestClient.get xxxxxx
      var = JSON.parse(xxxxx)
      render_on :view_issues_show_description_bottom, partial: 'redmine_rawfile/hooks/view_issues_show_description_bottom', locals: { var: var }
  end
end
```

My hook worked well and I am able to add my data under the issue description, but In my hook I have to know the current issue that I am working on, therefore I tried to pick my issue from the context object (puts context[:issue]) but I got this error:

```
Message from application: undefined local variable or method `context' for RedmineIssueRawFile::Hooks:Class (NameError)
```